# Upload the image in PDF using TCPDF and buttonImportIcon()

Tags: php, pdf, button, adobe, tcpdf

I'm using tcdf library to generate pdf. I would like to add a form in PDF where after pressing the button, the file selection window appears, and after selecting the photo, it automatically loads in the place of the button.
Everything is the same as in this video:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Y7F00jj6ntE

In TCPDF, the button is generated with
$ pdf-> Button ('ImportImage', 250, 250, 'Import Image', 'event.target.buttonImportIcon ()');

After downloading the PDF file and clicking this button, the file selection window opens, but the photo unfortunately does not load. Only the button background changes to white. I suspect that I should set some properties for the button. In the movie, the author sets "Layout" to "Icon only". How to set this property? I was looking at the TCPDF documentation, they recommend reading PDF32000_2008 there, but I can't find anything there. Does anyone know how to solve this?

[a screenshot of the TCPDF documentation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m5f5E.png)

Thank you in advance for any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I added "event.target.buttonPosition = 1;" to the button's JS code. This will change the button "layout" to "Icon only". Found this in the current version of Adobe documentation. In TCPDF in options I didn't notice that there is some key to changing this property. Therefore, it probably only remains to do it with JS.
I hope it will be useful to someone.